# Azure Data Factory - Bulk Import from Blob to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I have simple file **FD_GROUP.TXT** with content:

~0100~^~Dairy and Egg Products~
~0200~^~Spices and Herbs~
~0300~^~Baby Foods~
~0400~^~Fats and Oils~
~0500~^~Poultry Products~

I am trying to bulk import these files(some with 700,000 rows) to SQL database with Azure Data Factory.

Strategy is to first delimit columns with **^**, then I replace tildes(~) with empty character, so I lose tildes(~), then insertion happens.

***1. SQL solution:***

```
DECLARE @CsvFilePath NVARCHAR(1000) = 'D:\CodePurehope\Dev\NutrientData\FD_GROUP.txt';

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
 (
    [FoodGroupCode] VARCHAR(666) NOT NULL, 
    [FoodGroupDescription] VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
 )

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT #TempTable FROM ''' + @CsvFilePath + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR =''^'', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';
EXEC(@sql);

UPDATE #TempTable
   SET [FoodGroupCode] = REPLACE([FoodGroupCode], '~', ''),
       [FoodGroupDescription] = REPLACE([FoodGroupDescription], '~', '')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[FoodGroupDescriptions]
(
    [FoodGroupCode],
    [FoodGroupDescription]
)
SELECT
    [FoodGroupCode],
    [FoodGroupDescription]
FROM
    #TempTable
GO

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

***2. SSIS ETL package solution:***
[image]

Flat file source to delimit with **^** and derived column transformation to replace unnecessary tildes(~) as seen on the photo above.

**How do you do it with Microsoft Azure Data Factory?**
I have **FD_GROUP.TXT** uploaded on Azure Storage Blob as **input**, and table ready on Azure SQL Server for **output**.

I have:
- 2 linked services: AzureStorage and AzureSQL.
- 2 datasets: Blob as input and SQL as output
- 1 pipeline

[image]

***FoodGroupDescriptionsAzureBlob*** settings

```
{
    "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsAzureBlob",
    "properties": {
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "FoodGroupCode",
                "type": "Int32"
            },
            {
                "name": "FoodGroupDescription",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ],
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureBlob",
        "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileName": "FD_GROUP.txt",
            "folderPath": "nutrition-data/NutrientData/",
            "format": {
                "type": "TextFormat",
                "rowDelimiter": "\n",
                "columnDelimiter": "^"
            }
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 15
        }
    }
}
```

***FoodGroupDescriptionsSQLAzure*** settings

```
{
    "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsSQLAzure",
    "properties": {
        "structure": [
            {
                "name": "FoodGroupCode",
                "type": "Int32"
            },
            {
                "name": "FoodGroupDescription",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ],
        "published": false,
        "type": "AzureSqlTable",
        "linkedServiceName": "AzureSqlLinkedService",
        "typeProperties": {
            "tableName": "FoodGroupDescriptions"
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Minute",
            "interval": 15
        }
    }
}
```

***FoodGroupDescriptionsPipeline*** settings

```
{
    "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsPipeline",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Copy data from a blob to Azure SQL table",
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "Copy",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "BlobSource"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "SqlSink",
                        "writeBatchSize": 10000,
                        "writeBatchTimeout": "60.00:00:00"
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsAzureBlob"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsSQLAzure"
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "01:00:00",
                    "concurrency": 1,
                    "executionPriorityOrder": "NewestFirst"
                },
                "scheduler": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 15
                },
                "name": "CopyFromBlobToSQL",
                "description": "Bulk Import FoodGroupDescriptions"
            }
        ],
        "start": "2015-07-13T00:00:00Z",
        "end": "2015-07-14T00:00:00Z",
        "isPaused": false,
        "hubName": "gymappdatafactory_hub",
        "pipelineMode": "Scheduled"
    }
}
```

This thing doesn't work on Azure Data Factory + I have no clue how to use replace in this context. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Doesn't work,' are you getting a specific error?  Is this a one time import or something you are looking to schedule?

Comment: Just once. I mean nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using your code and I was able to get it working by doing the following:

In your FoodGroupDescriptionsAzureBlob json definition, you need to add "external": true in the properties node.  The Blob input file was created from an outside source not from an azure data factory pipeline, by setting this to true it lets azure data factory know that this input should be ready for use.

Also in the blob input definition add:
"quoteChar": "~" to the "format" node, since it looks like the data is wrapped with "~" this will strip those from the data that way the INT you defined will insert properly into your sql table.

Full blob def:

```
{
"name": "FoodGroupDescriptionsAzureBlob",
"properties": {
    "structure": [
        {
            "name": "FoodGroupCode",
            "type": "Int32"
        },
        {
            "name": "FoodGroupDescription",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ],
    "published": false,
    "type": "AzureBlob",
    "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService",
    "typeProperties": {
        "fileName": "FD_Group.txt",
        "folderPath": "nutrition-data/NutrientData/",
        "format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "rowDelimiter": "\n",
            "columnDelimiter": "^",
            "quoteChar": "~"
        }
    },
    "availability": {
        "frequency": "Minute",
        "interval": 15
    },
    "external": true,
    "policy": {}
}
```

}

Since you have the interval set for every 15 min and the pipelines start and end date for a full day this will create a slice every 15 min for the entire pipeline run duration, since you only want to run this once change the start and end to be this:

```
  "start": "2015-07-13T00:00:00Z",
  "end": "2015-07-13T00:15:00Z",
```

This will create 1 slice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works. Any specific source you got these external and quoteChar parameters from? If you have multiple tables, and they have to be moved to source in specified order because of the constraints, can we do it?

Comment: Here is a link about trouble shooting ADF issues : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-troubleshoot/  This makes reference to setting external to true.
Here is a link about copying from blob: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-blob-connector/
There is a section on the TextFormat node which has a description of all options.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use replace query like in my examples, because I get an error where field is empty: **Copy activity encountered a user error: Column 'CarbohydratesFactor' contains an invalid value ' '. Cannot convert ' ' to type 'Decimal'.**